# Gazebo no messages from sensor

Tags: ros, gazebo, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just trying to get a basic ROS-controlled gazebo sim with differential wheels and lidar.    I have followed the gazebo tutorial and am launching from this test.launch :

Then my world file has,

model://my_robot

And my_robot.sdf has

model://hokuyo
0.2 0 0.2 0 0 0


hokuyo::link
chassis

0 0 1

0
0

However when I run with
roslaunch test.launch

I see gazebo and the robot, but there are no Hokuyo messages appearing in rostopic.   Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

(I have tried editing hokuyo/model.sdf to
 /hokuyo_laser map 
but makes no difference)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216218/gazebo-no-messages-from-sensor/) by [charles.fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/22231/charles.fox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2015-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Self answer -- I'm using ROS Indigo and its gazebo, which are using  ~/.gazebo/models/hokuyo/model-1_4.sdf instead of hokuyu/model.sdf.    The required change to this file is

-->

then it works :)

---

Originally posted by [charles.fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/22231/charles.fox/) with karma: 120 on 2015-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0